# Repetitivas no funcionan en evento de botón. (Java)

Tags: java, java-swing, hilos

Estoy tratando de hacer un cronómetro, y resulta que al meter while dentro del evento click el JLabel no muestra nada y el botón de arranque queda presionado.
Al comentar el while dicho JLabel sí me despliega el valor de las variables cada vez que presiono el botón.

Acá va el código:

```html
package asdf;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

public class PruebaCronometroWB extends JFrame {

 private JPanel contentPane;
 private JLabel Horas;
 private JLabel Minutos;
 private JLabel Segundos;
 private boolean encendido = false;
 private int hs=0, mins=0, segs=0;
 

 /**
  * Launch the application.
  */
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
    try {
     PruebaCronometroWB frame = new PruebaCronometroWB();
     frame.setVisible(true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
   }
  });
 }

 /**
  * Create the frame.
  */
 public PruebaCronometroWB() {
  setResizable(false);
  setTitle("Cronómetro");
  setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  setBounds(100, 100, 337, 161);
  contentPane = new JPanel();
  contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
  setContentPane(contentPane);
  contentPane.setLayout(null);
  
  Horas = new JLabel("New label");
  Horas.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
  Horas.setBounds(12, 44, 70, 15);
  contentPane.add(Horas);
  
  Minutos = new JLabel("New label");
  Minutos.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
  Minutos.setBounds(127, 44, 70, 15);
  contentPane.add(Minutos);
  
  Segundos = new JLabel("New label");
  Segundos.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
  Segundos.setBounds(240, 44, 70, 15);
  contentPane.add(Segundos);
  
  JButton Inicio = new JButton("Inicio");
  Inicio.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
   @Override
   public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
    
    encendido = !encendido;
         
     while (encendido=true) {
     
      segs++;
      
      if (segs==60) {
       segs=0;
       mins++;
      }
      
      if (mins==60) {
       mins=0;
       hs++;
      }
     
      Segundos.setText(String.valueOf(segs));
            
      try {
       Thread.sleep(1000);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
       // TODO Auto-generated catch block
       e.printStackTrace();
      }
     
    }
    
   }
  });
  Inicio.setBounds(106, 83, 117, 25);
  contentPane.add(Inicio);
 }
}
```

Saludos.

Answer (score 3):

En Swing/AWT, el hilo de ejecución (*thread*) que refresca la pantalla es el mismo que procesa los eventos.

Lo que significa que mientras procesa un evento, la GUI no se refresca.

Si quieres ejecutar una lógica que tarde mucho tiempo (más de una o dos décimas de segundo), lo que debes hacer es pasarlo a un *thread* diferente para que deje libre el *thread* principal para refrescar el GUI. En tu caso, como se trata de una lógica que se está ejecutando siempre, creo que lo mejor sería extiendo Thread y lanzándolo directamente. Algo así como:

```
public class PruebaCronometroWB extends JFrame {
   private ThreadCronometro threadConometro;

   ...
   public PruebaCronometroWB() {

      public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
          encendido = !encendido;
          if (encendido) {
             threadCronometro = 
                new ThreadCronometro();
                ... // pasar las referencias a los elementos que necesita, etc.  
             threadCronometro.start();
          } else {
             threadCronometro.apagar(); // Para hacer que el thread salga de su bucle y termine.
          }
```

y, en ThreadCronometro

```
public class ThreadCronometro extends Thread {
   private boolean encendido = true;
   public void run() {              
       while (encendido) {
          ... // tu lógica aquí
       }
   }

   public void apagar() {
       encendido = false;
       this.interrupt(); // hacer que salga del wait
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema ocurre porque el código del evento corre en la hebra del UI, así no se actualiza nada mientras te quedas en el bloque `while` y el UI se congela.

Para solucionarlo puedes lanzar una nueva hebra que te actualiza el UI por ejemplo como clase anidada.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

public class PruebaCronometroWB extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JLabel Horas;
    private JLabel Minutos;
    private JLabel Segundos;
    private volatile boolean encendido = false;
    private int hs = 0, mins = 0, segs = 0;
    private Crono crono;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    PruebaCronometroWB frame = new PruebaCronometroWB();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public PruebaCronometroWB() {
        setResizable(false);
        setTitle("Cronómetro");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 337, 161);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        Horas = new JLabel("New label");
        Horas.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        Horas.setBounds(12, 44, 70, 15);
        contentPane.add(Horas);

        Minutos = new JLabel("New label");
        Minutos.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        Minutos.setBounds(127, 44, 70, 15);
        contentPane.add(Minutos);

        Segundos = new JLabel("New label");
        Segundos.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        Segundos.setBounds(240, 44, 70, 15);
        contentPane.add(Segundos);

        JButton Inicio = new JButton("Inicio");
        Inicio.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {

                encendido = !encendido;

                // call thread
                if (encendido) {
                    crono = new Crono();
                    crono.start();
                } else {
                    crono.interrupt();
                }

            }
        });
        Inicio.setBounds(106, 83, 117, 25);
        contentPane.add(Inicio);
    }

    class Crono extends Thread {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (encendido == true) {

                segs++;

                if (segs >= 60) {
                    segs -= 60;
                    mins++;
                }

                if (mins >= 60) {
                    mins -= 60;
                    hs++;
                }

                Segundos.setText(String.valueOf(segs));
                Minutos.setText(String.valueOf(mins));
                Horas.setText(String.valueOf(hs));

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    System.out.println(String.format("interrupted (encendido %b)",encendido));
                }

            }
        }

    }
}
```

Aparte de eso algunos comentarios:

Primero cometiste un error en la condición del `while`, comprobando:

```
while (encendido = true)
```

Eso no comprueba si encendido es `true`, pero asigna `true`a `encendido y luego evalua`true`. D3berías haber usado`encendido == true`.

Ademas el método de hacer la hebra dormir 1000 ms entre los incrementos no es preciso, porque el código también necesita su tiempo para ser ejecutado. Mejor sería guardar un sello de tiempo en el momento que actualizas el segundo y luego comparar cuanto tiempo pasó desde este sello en cada iteración para la proxima actualisación.