# ¿Cómo Hacer, para que se cumpla la secuencia Rojo, Amarillo y Verde?

Tags: java

Por favor, pueden ayudarme, esto es par un semáforo en una carrera de autos
No logro que se muestre el color amarillo, actualmente pasa a verde y se inicia la carrera.
Debería ser:

1. Mostrar Luz Roja y espera 5 Segundos más el mensaje Alto y la cuenta de los segundos
2. Mostrar Luz Amarilla y esperar 5 Segundos más el mensaje Esperar y la cuenta de los segundos
3. Mostara luz Verde, más el mensaje Partida y la cuenta final de los segundos

```
 for(int i=3; i>0; i--)
          
    {
     // System.out.println(i);
          jSemaforo.setText("Esperar "+i);
          
    //   try
         {
        // Thread.sleep(3000);
             //  System.out.println("Despues del Sleep " +i);
             //  Imagenes = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("amarillo.jpg"));  
              switch (i) {
                  case 3:
                    try
                      {
                       Thread.sleep(3000);
                       System.out.println("Despues del Case 3 " +i);
                       Imagenes = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("rojo.jpg"));
                       jSemaforo.setIcon(Imagenes);
                       break;
                    //  Thread.sleep(3000);
                      } catch(InterruptedException e){try {
                          throw e;
                  } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                      Logger.getLogger(JframeAuto.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                  }
                }
                        
                  case 2:
                      try {
                          
                         Thread.sleep(3000);
                         Thread.yield();
                         System.out.println("Despues del Case 2 " +i);
                         Imagenes = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("amarillo.jpg"));
                         jSemaforo.setIcon(Imagenes);
                         jSemaforo.setText("Esperar "+i);
                      }catch(InterruptedException e){}
                      System.out.println("Despues del Sleep 2 " +i);
                      break;
              //} ///Aqui
                  case 1:
                      try {
                        Thread.sleep(3000);
                        
                        System.out.println("Despues del Case 1 " +i);
                        Imagenes = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("verde.jpg"));
                        jSemaforo.setIcon(Imagenes);
                        jSemaforo.setText("Partida "+i);
                         break; 
                      }catch(InterruptedException e){}
                      
                  default:
                      break;
              }
         } //
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Repetitivas no funcionan en evento de botón. (Java)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/75425/repetitivas-no-funcionan-en-evento-de-bot%c3%b3n-java)

Answer (score 0):

```
Thread.yield();
```

Lo más probable es que esta llamada impida que se ejecute. Te bastaría con borrar esa línea.